# capturing web-sockets packets from IOS using fiddler

Tags: ios, fiddler

I am using latest **Fiddler** version trying to capture **web-sockets** requests from an **IOS application**.

I am able to see only **HTTP** and **HTTPS** requests.

*Laptop*(Running fiddler on port 8888) and mobile both are on same network

- Laptop IP - 192.168.4.2
- mobile IP - 192.168.4.3 proxy configured to 192.168.4.2 port 8888

Is there any thing am missing out?..

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: nah, burp recent update supports websockets through repeater. I'm sticking with that for now. But still I need to know the answer.